# Unique Lines and Words? How to implement it?

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with this program. The program is supposed to tell the user the number of lines, words, characters, unique lines, and unique words there are in a given input. So far, words and characters are okay. However, if the user wants to input more than one line, how do I do that? The functions will only output the results of **one line** at a time, rather than adding the results of both lines together. Also, I can't get the Unique Lines and Unique Words to work properly. I just got into C++ so I don't really have much experience. Can someone please help me?

Problems:

1. Program reads one line at a time, so when the user inputs multiple times, the program produces the results separately rather than adding it together as one entity.
2. Unique Lines and Unique Words are not working. Any ideas how to implement it using the library used in the program.

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   using std::cin;
   using std::cout;
   using std::endl;
   #include <string>
   using std::string;
   #include <set>
   using std::set;


   // write this function to help you out with the computation.


   unsigned long countLines()
   {
       return 1;
   }



   unsigned long countWords(const string& s)
   {
       int nw =1;
       for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
       {
           if (s[i] == ' ')  //everytime the function encounters a whitespace, count     increases by 1)//
           {
               nw++;
           }
       }
    return nw;
   }

   unsigned long countChars(const string& s)
   {
       int nc = 0;
       for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
       {
           if ( s[i] != ' ') //everytime the function encounters a character other than a whitespace, count increases//
           {
               nc++;
           }
       }

       return nc;
   }


   unsigned long countUnLines(const string& s, set<string>& wl)
   {
      wl.insert(s);
      return wl.size();
   }



   unsigned long countUnWords(const string& s, set<string>& wl)
   {
       int m1 = 0;
       int m2 = 0;
       string substring;

       for(m2 = 0; m2 <= s.size(); m2++){
           if (m2 != ' ' )

           substring = s.substr(m1,m2);
           wl.insert(substring);

           m1 = m2 + 2;}
       }

       return wl.size();

       int unw = 0;
       wl.insert(s);
       unw++;
       return unw;
   }

   int main()
   {
       //stores string
       string s;

       //stores stats
       unsigned long Lines = 0;
       unsigned long Words = 0;
       unsigned long Chars = 0;
       unsigned long ULines = 0;
       unsigned long UWords = 0;

       //delcare sets
       set<string> wl;

       while(getline(cin,s))
       {

           Lines += countLines();
           Words += countWords(s);
           Chars += countChars(s);
           ULines += countUnLines(s,wl);
           UWords += countUnWords(s);

           cout << Lines << endl;
           cout << Words<< endl;
           cout << Chars << endl;
           cout << ULines << endl;
           cout << UWords << endl;


           Words = 0;
           Chars = 0;
           ULines = 0;
           UWords = 0;

       }

       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: You are showing a lot of commented lines, many of which answer the questions you were asking.  What you posted currently doesn't run, since `main` is commented out, but in there, it's properly reading the lines.  Move your `cout`s outside of the while loop, and remove setting all the stuff to 0 at the end of your loop.  Also, the code that checks the words in the lines has a bug: `"one word[6 spaces]a"` will result in 8 words.

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting your count variables to zero at the end of your getline while loop.  This is why you are only getting results for one line.  The user can input multiple lines in your program as it is right now you are just resetting the count.

Comment: Or dump each line/word into std::set or std::unordered_set and then output the .size().

Comment: However, when I remove those reset counters, each time I input lines, the counter continues from where it left off. For example I input one line, it outputs 1. Then when I input another line, it outputs 2 when it should say 1.

Comment: Well i guess that is up to you. It sounded like you wanted to accumlate them across line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're headed in the right direction. In order to count unique lines and words you're gonna have to store every line and word in a data structure of some kind, I'd suggest an unordered_map. Each element in the map you'll have a counter for # of occurences of each line/word.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to give the answer away wholesale, but here are some ideas to get you started.

1. The function getline() can read in an entire line of input. Do this until there's no more input.
2. You can use a container like std::set (or better, std::unordered_set) to store the lines read in. Not the most efficient, but it keeps track of all your lines, and only stores the unique ones.
3. Each line can then be broken down into words. Consider using something like std::stringstream for this.
4. Store the words in a different std::unordered_set.
5. The number of unique lines (words) is simply the number of lines (words) stored in the containers. Use the .size() method to obtain this.

Doing the total number of lines, words, and characters can be computed as you read the data in, so I won't go into much detail there.

Each item is googleable, and you may choose to implement different parts differently (if you don't want to use a stringstream, you can always iterate over the line read, for example.) This should get you on the right track.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. I try dumping the string into the set and just have the program return the size of the set. However, the counter just keeps increasing with each line and nothing changes.

Comment: For example, I input a line, the output says one for unique lines. Then when I do it again, the count goes up to two when there should only be one.

Comment: It sounds like you're not counting things correctly then. For every iteration of reading in a line, you should be a) updating a "total lines" counter, and b) throwing the line into a set. At the end of the loop, you will have a counter that stores the total lines read, and a set containing every unique line. Do the same logic for for words and you're pretty much done.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm sorry I really have no experience regarding c++. I don't think I can just store the counter every time.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to get *fairly* accurate counts, but can be surprisingly difficult to get correct counts for all of this.

The big problem is the character count. If you open the file (as you usually would) in text mode, the number of characters you count may not match what the OS thinks is there. For the obvious examples, under Windows a CR/LF pair will be translated to a single new-line character, so you'll typically count each line as one character shorter than it really is.

Technically, there's no way to deal with that entirely correctly either -- the translation from external to internal representation when a file is opened in text mode is theoretically arbitrary. At least in theory, opening in binary mode doesn't help a lot either; in binary mode, you can have an arbitrary number of NUL characters after the end of the data that was written to the file.

The latter, however, is pretty much theoretical these days (it was allowed primarily because of CP/M, which most people have long forgotten).

To read lines, but retain the line-end delimiters intact, you can use `std::cin.get()` instead of `std::getline()`, then read the delimiters separately from the line itself.

That gives us something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    static char line[4096];
    unsigned long chars = 0;
    unsigned long words = 0;
    unsigned long lines = 0;
    std::set<std::string> unique_words;

    std::ifstream in(argv[1], std::ios::binary);

    while (in.get(line, sizeof(line), '\n')) {
        ++lines;
        chars += strlen(line);

        std::istringstream buffer(line);
        std::string word;
        while (buffer >> word) {
            ++words;
            unique_words.insert(word);
        }
        while (in.peek() == '\n' || in.peek() == '\r') {
            ++chars;
            in.ignore(1);
        }       
    }
    std::cout << "words: " << words << "\n"
              << "lines: " << lines << "\n"
              << "chars: " << chars << "\n"
              << "unique words: " << unique_words.size() << "\n";
}
```

Note that although this *does* answer that the OP actually asked at least for most typical OSes (Linux, *BSD, MacOS, Windows), it's probably *not* what he really wants. My guess is that his teacher isn't really asking for this level of care to try to get an accurate character count.

Also note that *if* you should encounter a line longer than the buffer, this can still give an inaccurate count of lines -- it'll count each buffer-full of data as a separate line, even if it didn't find a line-delimiter. That can be fixed as well, but it adds still more complexity to a program that's almost certainly already more complex than intended.